# What's the name of this tamper proof screw ? (looking for screwdriver type)

Tags: screw-terminal

I'm trying to fix device witch contain tamper proof screw witch i'm unable to recognize. I have set of standard tamper proof screwdrivers but i'm unable to find any suitable.

Could someone recognize this screw and point me what's the name of it so i could search e-bay for right screwdriver?
[image: unknown tamper proof screw]
Regards

Comment: When I came across one of these recently, I simply took an old screwdriver and used my Dremel to cut off the original tip and then grind a new triangular tip. The fact that the handle had six sides made it easy to get the angles right. It only took a few minutes, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: Dave, Your solution sounds quite nice. In other comments I found right answer for the head name, but prices are quite high for opening 4 screws. I'm going to follow Your idea, after opening i will put normal screws.  Tank You

Comment: Those look like the screws in a Nintendo DS.  You can get one of the DS TriWing screwdrivers for US$1.  Google "nintendo ds screwdriver".  You might try that.

Comment: See http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/2701

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a triangle headed screw to me. I had to get a set of [drivers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B004KFHHVQ/ref=pe_217191_31005151_dp_1) for these a while ago. In this set are  TA18, TA20, TA23 and a TA27 - Triangular Allen key perhaps?

Comment: You have right, it's looks just like mine. I will try to make myself that screwdriver if not work... i will have to measure somehow this screw and order this set. Regards

Answer (score 1):

Looks like either a TA ("delta") or [TP3](http://rightsock.com/~kjw/Sale/tp3.html) drive.

Edit: On closer examination (on a real monitor) the sides of the triangle appear to be straight, which means it's a TA as pattyhoyts suggested.